# checkbox gets auto selected from my previous page load

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have list of check boxes which do not have "checked" keyword on html page. Ex say I have checboxes for a1, b1, c1.

After the page loads, I select a1 and b1 in UI. When I refresh the page, the a1 and b1 are getting checked autmatically even though though they are not marked as checked in my html. How to fix this?

I have just tested the above one in firefox browser.

Comment: You could use Javascript with or without jQuery so you can unselect all checkbox when the page load.

Answer (score 1):

You should use autocomplete = "off" attribute. You will find more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

Have a function to clear all boxes upon page load  using JS's form handling

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function clearCheck() {
 var form = document.forms["form"];
for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
            form.elements[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
 }

 }
 </script>

<body onload='clearCheck()'> 
 <form name='form'>    
 <input type='checkbox' name='a1' value='a1'><br>
 <input type='checkbox' name='b1' value='b1'><br>
 <input type='checkbox' name='c1' value='c1'>
 </form>
```